# Generic interface in Java

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to have something like that? I'm trying to force any class extending this one to implement an interface that extends `BaseHomeListView`

```
public abstract class BaseHomeFragment<T extends BaseHomeListView> extends BaseRecyclerViewFragment implements T
```

I'm trying to implement MVP pattern in Android for some fragments which only display lists. 
So basically the view has to rendersList, that's why it is in the base interface, however I still want to allow each fragment to have add more methods as they need

```
public interface BaseHomeListView<T> extends LoadDataView, LoadMoreView<T> {
   void renderList(Collection<T> items);
}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to acheive here? What's your use-case?

Comment: *`implements T`*. No. You can't use RTTI to specify a compile time check.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Why don't you simply implement BaseHomeListView in your BaseHomeFragment? it is already abstract, so you can implement that interface without actually having to implement the methods.

Answer (score 2):

The only sensible thing you can do is the following:

```
public abstract class BaseHomeFragment<T> 
    extends BaseRecyclerViewFragment 
    implements BaseHomeListView<T>
```

And then if you have something like

```
public interface FancyHomeListView extends BaseHomeListView<Fancy> {
}
```

Then you can just have a fragment like

```
public class FancyHomeFragment 
    extends BaseHomeFragment<Fancy>
    implements FancyHomeListView {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the implementation of the interface's methods in every subclass, but not the arguments of such methods, or decouple the business code of the fragment's views, it would be more reasonable to add a generic instance of such interface as a member of your fragment class.

```
    public abstract class BaseHomeFragment<T extends BaseHomeListView> extends BaseRecyclerViewFragment {

/*the class information can be used against a factory method to get an instance of the interface*/
private Class<T> myInterfaceClass;
protected T myInterfaceInstance;

public void setMyInterFaceInstance(T instance){
myInterfaceInstance = instance;
}

public BaseHomeFragment(Class<T> initializeClass){
myInterfaceClass = initializeClass;
myInterfaceInstance = interfaceFactory(myInterfaceClass);

}

//TODO: use the interface instance.

}
```

now, in every subclass, you'll need to add the interface subclass as an argument to super:

```
public class myAppHomeFragment extends BaseHomeFragment<AppHomeListView>{

public myAppHomeFragment(){
super(AppHomeListView.class);
setMyInterFaceInstance(new AppHomeListView{
//Method overloading
});

}
//TODO: Use the interface's new methods if necessary.

}
```

a little example of your factory method:

```
public static <T extends BaseHomeListView> T interfaceFactory(Class<T> aClass){

if(aClass.getSimpleName().equals("someclass")){
//TODO
return new someclass;
}
return null;
}
```